# Migrating to / Getting started with AngularJS AND Web Development

Tags: angularjs, web-applications, angular

I have an old Java-based tool (client=J2SE app; server=J2EE .ear app) which I have to migrate to a newer technology stack. Biggest part of the changes will affect the client-side, and the chosen solution is *Angular **2*** (though not-sure yet if JS or TypeScript...).

My experience is mostly focused on backend development, and even though I did some web development in the past, I'm lacking knowledge about the modern versions of it (solid concepts, good practices, etc.).

***What I need:*** (*I assume, in the end, this question is more on general web development than on Angular*)

- some help for finding proper guidance (documentation) through the initial steps (I'm not in a time crisis, but I don't have a lot either);
- some links to useful tutorials, or even books, helpful for catching-up with the most important aspects & concepts of web development.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question is inappropriate for SO. Please check the help menu about what question (not) to ask.

Comment: True. Found it.
Sorry for this mistake...